# Using replace string function in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, string, replace

Within an attribute table, I'm trying to replace one string with another using the `replace` function.  As an example, there are a number of features whose field `"NAME"` contains the string '(B)' and I'm wanting to replace this with the word 'County'. I'm selecting the 'update existing field' checkbox and using the following expression

```
 replace('(B)', '(B)', 'County')
```

The end result is that the field `"NAME"` for every feature is replaced by 'County' irrespective of whether or not the field `"NAME"` originally contained the string '(B)'.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 37):

```
replace( '(B)','(B)','County')
```

tells QGIS to replace the '(B)' in '(B)' with 'Country'.

You want

```
replace("Name",'(B)','Country')
```

= replace the '(B)' in "Name" with 'Country'.

Note that the **double quotes indicate a field name** while the **single quotes refer to a static string**. These are not interchangeable.

Comment: @GrahamD please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 12):

The proper syntax is:

```
replace([field_name], '(B)', 'Country')
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, open the Field Calculator and select the replace function from the string option like the following picture:

[image]

Secondly, tells QGIS to replace the replace `("Field Name", '(B)', 'Country')`. For example in this case

```
replace("MES_TIP", 'T', 'Rock')
```

Thirdly, please choose the output field type: text(string), and then determine the field name

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The interface looks a little different now and you have to select the column from the menu in the drop-down on the left-*abc name*

I also noted that words in the single quotations have to be exact including no extra spaces. (which stumped me briefly)

I was replacing the word Road with Rd. in this example.

```
replace("name", 'Road', 'Rd.')
```

Press Update Filtered to make the change. It can take a while...as this OSM file did.

Filtering out a huge table would help speed up the replacement process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a small plugin available now, which wraps *regex_replace* in a small GUI:

[Field find/replace](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis-plugin-findreplace-main/)

Comment: It's painfully slow... not usable with larger datasets, and does not have a cancel button to stop action. Quite bad "plugin"