# Field Calculator - replace string function - data value recognised as a column and is "not found"

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have the same challenge as GrahamD - [How to use the replace string function in Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78659/field-calculator-replace-string-function#comment108255_78659)

I have exactly the same challenge.

Exactly the same as GrahamD's challenge, p abbreviated for pan. Type_2 as a test column. duplicated.

Using underdark and eseglem's formulars/advice here is the copy and paste directly from the expression box:

```
replace("Type_2", "p", "pan")
```

All text and quotations in red. ok button greyed out.

> Output preview: expression invalid Parser Error: (nothing detailed) Eval Error: Column 'p' not found

I get exactly the same results should I swop Type_2 and p around.

Answer (score 2):

In the Field Calculator;

- a "field"
- a 'value in the field'

what you do is :

- replace in field "Type2" field "p" by field "pan"

then what you want to do is:

- replace in field "Type2" value 'p' by value 'pan'

so:

```
replace("Type_2", 'p', 'pan')
```