# Replace using regular expression?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a layer with column "ADDL_INFO" having values like
BM 12.4
BM 140!5
BM 320.6
BM 22!5

I want to change '!' mark with '.'

How to change it in qgis 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in the field calculator

```
replace("ADDL_INFO", '!', '.')
```

However, your question was answered already here:
[How to use the replace string function in Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78659/how-to-use-the-replace-string-function-in-field-calculator)